# foreach loop for joined tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to list users inside a loop but I want to keep the city_name outside the loop. Do I need another query or if statement for that?

What I exactly want as result :

LONDON USERS:
JAMES, BOB

NEW YORK USERS:
DAVID

```
users table
====================
id  user_name   user_city_id  user_type
1   Helen       2             NA
2   James       1             PREMIUM
3   David       1             NORMAL
4   Bob         1             NORMAL

cities table
=============
city_id  city_name  city_status
1        London     1
2        New York   1
3        Paris      0

<?php 

    $getcities = $db->get_rows("
        SELECT * 
        FROM users
        JOIN cities 
        ON cities.city_id = users.user_city_id
        WHERE city_status = '1'
        AND user_type IN ('NORMAL','PREMIUM')
    ");

?>

<h1><?php echo $row->city_name ?> USERS</h1>

<?php
    foreach($getcities as $row) {
?>

<h2><?php echo $row->user_name ?></h2>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: what is inside $row before the foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a SQL query.

```
    SELECT cities.city_name, GROUP_CONCAT(users.user_name) AS names
    FROM users INNER JOIN cities ON cities.city_id = users.user_city_id
    WHERE city_status = '1' AND user_type IN ('NORMAL','PREMIUM')
    GROUP BY cities.city_id
```

In your PHP

```
    foreach($getcities as $row) {
          echo $row->city_name . ": " . $row->names;
    }
```

Comment: What if I need to echo another row from users table ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to list users by city you need to switch up your join, or you need to re-structure your data on the application level, which is never good, but sometimes necessary, IMO.

There are quite a bunch of issues with your example, however to do what you aim, change your SQL to

```
SELECT * 
FROM cities
JOIN users
ON cities.city_id = users.user_city_id
WHERE city_status = '1'
AND user_type IN ('NORMAL','PREMIUM')
```

Then

```
<?php
$lastCity = null;
foreach($getcities as $row):
?>

    <?php if($row->city_name !== $lastCity): $lastCity = $row->city_name; ?>
        <h1><?php echo $row->city_name ?> USERS</h1>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <h2><?php echo $row->user_name ?></h2>

<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Is there a way to group users by cities? I have tried GROUP BY city_name but it shows only 2 records

Comment: @BlueCat That is exactly what I have shown you how to do.